# Rails 5: How Do I Set Up a Merge Tool to use for rails app:update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-5, mergetool, app-update

I'm upgrading a rails 5.2.4.1 app to rails 6. There are a few config files I want to merge instead of manually adding information from a copy of the old file.

The first time I entered m to merge the file I got the following message.

```
Please specify merge tool to `THOR_MERGE` env.
```

I did a search and found this [blog post](https://medium.com/@dannylee8/week-5-lip-notes-ruby-on-rails-a4b66f24cecf). The folder that this person found after Googling does not exist on my Mac computer.

FileMerge doesn't exist and DiffMerge is very old. I haven't found any information about using one with `rails app:update`.

What Mac merge tools are currently used that I can set the env var THOR_MERGE to?

Comment: I believe `/usr/bin/code` is referencing the binary for VS Code. I have a `.env` file in my directory and set `THOR_MERGE=code`. That did the trick. Not sure if it is what I want, but I believe that is what the author of that post meant.

Comment: Okay thanks so much!

Answer (score 24):

Stumbled upon this answer searching for the same thing.

You can launch vscode diff tool by setting the `THOR_MERGE` env variable as follows:

```
THOR_MERGE="code -d $1 $2"
```

This is assuming you have code in your PATH, which you can setup by following the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line).

Comment: When I set things up this way, I get a "sh: code: command not found", even though I have VS code installed

Comment: @Dave did you follow the instruction found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that XCode includes /usr/bin/opendiff, which is a binary that launches FileMerge.app. So I was able to:`THOR_MERGE=opendiff rails app:update`

Comment: when I tried this it blew up on yml files

Comment: OS X 12.6.4 gives me this error: `xcode-select: error: tool 'opendiff' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

Answer (score 8):

RubyMine can also be used as the merge tool. To make that work on my macOS Monterey system, I created a new Bash script at `/usr/local/bin/rubymine-merge` (based in part on the `rubymine` script provided by JetBrains Toolbox) with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -- wait="-W"

bundle exec rubocop --server -A "$1"

open -na "$HOME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/RubyMine/ch-0/222.3739.56/RubyMine 2022.2 EAP.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine" $wait --args merge "$2" "$1" "$2"
```

After this, I was able to invoke the Rails update script as follows:

```
THOR_MERGE=rubymine-merge bin/rails app:update
```

This is working as of RubyMine 2022.2.1 in mid-August of 2022.

The Rails update script seems to require that the merge tool behave as if it had received a `--wait` parameter, because after the last merge the script deletes all temporary files. Passing `--wait` as a command-line parameter seems problematic with the 2022.2 version of the command-line script, so I hard-coded the `-W` on line 3.

I also inserted a call to *rubocop* on line 5 so that the proposed changes from the Rails app:update script would already be aligned with the standards for this project. Skip that part if it's not meeting your needs. I had to use `bundle exec rubocop` instead of `bin/rubocop` because the Rails app:update script is not always running in the context of the root directory of your project.

It is suboptimal for this script be separate from the `/usr/local/bin/rubymine` script that is generated by JetBrains Toolbox. Every time a new version of RubyMine is installed, the path to the actual RubyMine application can change.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but the script is going to need an update every time the Toolbox decides to change folder / app name etc. I wonder if there isn't an easier way to find the path...

Comment: This worked for me where VS code didn't `wait`. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Raithlin, the JetBrains team recently added a comment in their bug reporting system stating that the path is now unchanging.

Comment: I just set up this script and changed the last line pointing to the executable inside the .app file to the current version and it works. It seems like you should just be able to point to the value of `which rubymine` but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple Solution:

`THOR_MERGE=kdiff3 rails app:update`

- or use `opendiff` / `meld` / `kdiff` etc.
- Credit to @pduey (thanks).